# Apply changes from Live Property Explorer in WPF

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2015

I am new to WPF.

I am debugging a simple program and playing around with the the Live Visual Tree and Live Property Explorer to make changes on the fly.

My simple question is, Can I apply those changes straight into my XAML code or to I have to keep 2 versions of Visual Studio open? One for Debugging and one for editing?

Comment: Use one instance of VS. You'll have to make changes in your XAML by hand; there's no round-trip between Live Property Tree and the XAML source code.

Comment: Do I need to remember my changes. Am I the only who thinks that would be a good feature

Comment: Nothing's going to remember your changes for you. I've never used those features that way, and I can't recall hearing about anybody else doing so. You may be one of the few. More experienced WPF people tend to work in the XAML editor, with occasional recourse to the designer just to make sure it looks like it should.

Comment: When I work on a website in chrome I edit the CSS on the inspector and then copy the edited CSS into Visual Studio.  I was looking for the same Idea

Comment: That sounds like a nice way to work. I wonder if Blend might do something like that? I've hardly used it.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I apply those changes straight into my XAML code or to I have to keep 2 versions of Visual Studio open?

No and Yes. Visual Studio won't update the XAML for you. You will have to do this manually yourself.

You may want to suggest this as a new Visual Studio feature on [uservoice.com](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide).